Getting a 500 Error response when using estimate API endpoint
I am getting a 500 error when calling this endpoint. The safe exists. The transaction follows the API syntax.
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://safe-transaction-sepolia.safe.global/api/v1/safes/0x7AC3F72019a6dA4E7de65236bd756A97B53a64d4/multisig-transactions/estimations/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'X-CSRFToken: 5T4L6BGELuOMFYM2b34gzdALrVTqubkQj3glzJjKq1PuVYFq2AO9gCedFyDEKftv' \
  -d '{
"to":"0x7cbB62EaA69F79e6873cD1ecB2392971036cFAa4",
"value":0,
"data":"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",
"operation":1,
"nonce":0
}'

For context, I am trying to use the hardhat-safe-deployer in combination with the diamond feature of hardhat deploy. This is the first transaction it tries to send, to estimate gas for deploying a library. It's not the framework (yet) because this also doesn't work within Swapper or as shown here, with just CURL.

Is this a real company and real system ?

I am not sure I understood why you are using Safe API for a hardhat deployment; do you want the safe to be the library's deployer? I am not sure to understand either what you mean by 'It's not the framework (yet)'. Could you please elaborate? Thanks a lot in advance  Best, Louis

Yes. I want the safe to be the deployer.  I have not had any success of failure I can blame on the framework (hardhat-deploy + hardhat-safe-deployer + diamond) because obviously your servers return a 500 on this call with just curl.
If there is a problem with the payload, I would love to know what it is.

Why does it take 2 days for someone to tell me what's wrong with a request that follows the format in their documentation ?

We're looking into the problem. It looks indeed that your call follows the expected format, so we're currently investigating why it returns a 500. Please hang tight in the meantime

There was indeed a check missing on our end. You can track the issue resolution here: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-transaction-service/issues/2203. Thanks for hanging tight while we are working on the issue

Any update besides just opening a GitHub ticket ?

There was some progress indeed, as the root cause of the problem was solved (here: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-eth-py/pull/1327); we are still awaiting a new release so that is included in the newest infrastructure deployment. You will be able to follow the issue aforementioned for further progress. The team is working hard to release this as soon as possible, so feel free to check again in a few days, or let me know here if this does not work out. Thanks in advance
